# Which episode does Shion take the whole day to send a single text?

Tags: shion-no-o

Which episode of Shion no Ou does Shion take the whole day to send a single text? I believe it was to Ayumi. I think it was somewhere episodes 12 to 22 (the latter half of the series) and in the latter half of whatever episode it was in.

---

Edit: Thanks to Turamarth it's in episode 16. I was right about that. However

[image]

> It took me an entire day to write one text.

I was wrong that it was in the latter half of the episode. It was actually in the former half, around 9:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog](https://iamundercover.wordpress.com/2008/03/06/shion-no-ou-ep-16/) the scene happens in episode 16.

> A blushing Shion wishes to send a text message to Ayumi but can’t seem think of anything to say. It took her the whole day before she came up with something to say.

Comment: THANK YOU Turamarth. Have you actually watched the series? If not: Then how did you come across this blog? What keywords did you use to search it? Did you just search "shion" "text" "ayumi"? Or what?

Comment: @BCLC I simply searched for "shion no ou sms". The third hit was that blog.